# How to remove from a list 'setequally' duplicated elements in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have some list *li* in R whose elements are vectors. For instance,

```
li=list(a=c(2,3,5),b=c(77,119,81),c=c(9,11,13),d=c(5,2,3),e=c(80,45,16),f=c(16,17,19),g=c(13,9,11),h=c(22,13,58))
```

It can be seen that all objects in *li* are different **as vectors**. Therefore,

```
duplicated(li)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Also, the command `unique(li)` will return the same list *li*. But note that the elements a and d as well as c and g are equal **as sets**. Namely,

```
setequal(li$a,li$d)
[1] TRUE
```

and

```
setequal(li$c,li$g)
[1] TRUE
```

Consequently, the element a is duplicated **as set** by the element d and the element c is duplicated **as set** by the element g. My question is: How to remove from a list such 'setequally' duplicated elements in R ?

Comment: Do you want to remove all duplicated parts, i.e. a _and_ d for example or only d? To remove all parts, akrun's answer seems coorect, otherwise you can use `li[!duplicated(lapply(li, function(x) sort(unique(x))))]`.

Comment: Thanks for your asswer. I was interested in both options, i.e., in removing all duplicated parts as well as in removing only one duplicated elements from each pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
li[apply(sapply(li, function(x) sapply(li, setequal, x)), 2, sum)==1]

$b
[1]  77 119  81

$e
[1] 80 45 16

$f
[1] 16 17 19

$h
[1] 22 13 58
```

?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the `unique` `sort`ed elements and then remove all the `set` equal elements with `duplicated`

```
li1 <- lapply(li, function(x) sort(unique(x)))
i1 <- !(duplicated(li1)|duplicated(li1, fromLast = TRUE))
li[i1]
#$b
#[1]  77 119  81

#$e
#[1] 80 45 16

#$f
#[1] 16 17 19

#$h
#[1] 22 13 58
```

Comment: Thanks for aswer. In many cases the above code is sufficcient. Thanks.